# Magic dice question.

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

A pair of dice are magic. When they are rolled together, then half the time, they behave like a normal pair of dice, but the other half of the time they miraculously roll a double ( equally likely to be any of the six possible doubles).  What is the expected value of the product of the two scores when the pair of dice are rolled?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In the case of magic: a double is rolled and the probability is 0.5, and so for each double the probability must be 1/12. For regular dice, probability is 0.5, and for each outcome the probability must be 1/60? Although I am not sure I am on the right lines.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the sample space as $(M,n,m)$ where $M=0$ if the dice behave normally and $M=1$ otherwise. $n,m \in \{1,...,6\}$. $M, n,m $ are independent and uniformly distributed as appropriate. Hence $P[(M,n,m) ] = {1 \over 2 \cdot 6^2}$.

Define $f(M,n,m) = \begin{cases} nm,& M=0 \\
n^2, & M=1\end{cases}$.

Then $E[f] = {1 \over 2 \cdot 6^2} (\sum_n \sum_m nm + 6 \sum_n n^2) = {1 \over 2 \cdot 6^2} ((\sum_n n)^2 + 6 \sum_n n^2) = {329 \over 24} \approx 13.708$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

There are 2 cases, on average with equal weight:

1. *Magic happens:* then there are 6 outcomes with equal probability, can you compute the expected value for this case?
2. *No magic happens:* then you have regular dice, can you compute the expected value for this case?
3. Average the expectations for (1) and (2).

Comment: I've attempted this and got the expected value to be 3.5 when the magic happens, and 3.5 for regular dice? 1) each outcome would be 1/12, and for 2) it would be 1/60? Am I right?

Comment: @Aizen You want the expected value of the **product** of the two dice, not the **sum** of the two dice.

Comment: @user2661923 I am getting 12.25 for the product of the expected values, however the right answer is 13.47. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Aizen see my answer, which numerically agrees with the answer of copper.hat.  One possible source of ambiguity is if one is supposed to assume that when the dice are **not** magic, that **doubles can't happen**.  Neither copper.hat nor I made such an assumption, since this assumption is not supported by your query.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to calculate the 36 cross sums (1/2) the problem is to note that

$$(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) \times (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) = 441.$$

Therefore, 1/2 of the time, the expected product is

$$\frac{441}{36}.$$

$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 = 91.$$

Therefore, 1/2 of the time, the expected product is

$$\frac{91}{6} = \frac{546}{36}.$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \times \left(\frac{441}{36} + \frac{546}{36}\right)
~=~ \frac{987}{72} ~\approx~ 13.708.$$